# Как правильнее организовать локализацию сайта по ключам. Где хранить перевод?

Tags: php

Сейчас на всех страницах вместо текста пишется

```php
echo $tr->get('localization_key');
```

Вопрос в том как и где хранить сам перевод ключей. Если хранить их в базе, значит что это 300-400 запросов к базе с каждого пользователя, зашедшего на сайт.

Если хранить в массиве то придётся на каждой странице в код подключать абсолютно все переводы, а их может быть несколько тысяч.

Подскажите как правильнее хранить перевод. Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хранить в массиве и подключать на каждый запрос.

С учетом [opcode cache](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.opcache.php) это не предсталяет для пхп ни малейшей проблемы.

Comment: Подключать вообще все? Или как-то разделить их?

Comment: Подключать вообще все